# ML Model: ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 150528 while Y.shape[1] == 512

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

So I am trying to train a model with some images and then the model should detect whether its similar to the images trained or not the training part works good I guess it generates .npy file then the calculating similarity file loads that file and tries to calculate the similarity here is the code for that

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from PIL import Image
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch
import os


# Load the pre-trained features
features = np.load('features.npy')

# Define a function to calculate cosine similarity between an image and features
def calculate_similarity(image, features, transformer):
    # Apply the same transformations used for training data
    image = transformer(image)

    # Extract features from the input image
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension
    
    # Flatten both the image and features
    image_flat = image.view(1, -1)
    features_flat = features.reshape(features.shape[0], -1)

    # Now calculate cosine similarity
    similarity = cosine_similarity(image_flat, features_flat)

    return similarity

# Define a function to check if an image is similar to the training set
def is_similar(image, features, transformer, threshold=0.7):
    similarity = calculate_similarity(image, features, transformer)
    return similarity.max() >= threshold

# Example usage for processing images in a directory
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Define the transformation pipeline for both training and test data
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    ])

    # Directory containing the images
    image_dir = 'data/train'

    # List all files in the directory
    image_files = [os.path.join(image_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(image_dir) if f.endswith('.jpeg')]

    for image_path in image_files:
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        is_similar_image = is_similar(image, features, transform)

        if is_similar_image:
            print(f"The image {image_path} is similar to the training set.")
        else:
            print(f"The image {image_path} is not similar to the training set.")
```

So the above code is for the calculating similarity when I run this it gives the following error

**ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 150528 while Y.shape[1] == 512**

Just in case if needed heres the file which trains the ml model

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torchvision import models
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
import os
from PIL import Image
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

# Define the custom dataset for image loading
class ImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.image_filenames = os.listdir(root_dir)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_filenames)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.image_filenames[idx])
        image = Image.open(img_name)
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image

# Set the data directory containing your training images
data_dir = 'data/train'

# Define data transformations for the model
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

# Create a custom dataset and data loader
dataset = ImageDataset(data_dir, transform=transform)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

# Load a pre-trained ResNet model
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
model = nn.Sequential(*list(model.children())[:-1])  # Remove the final classification layer

# Extract features from images using the pre-trained model
model.eval()
features = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for inputs in dataloader:
        inputs = inputs.to('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else inputs
        outputs = model(inputs)
        features.extend(outputs.cpu().numpy())

# Save the extracted features to a file
import numpy as np

features = np.array(features)
np.save('features.npy', features)
```

Comment: After Obtaining outputs you should `flatten` the features before extending them by `outputs = outputs.view(outputs.size(0), -1)`.